Problems Mounting 12 TB USB Drive
I have 3 USB self powered drives, 2x 6TB and a 12TB.
The 2x 6TB mount correctly under user 5001:users, The 12 TB I have changed to be the same,
drwxrwxrwx 4 5001 users 69632 Nov 11  2023 Films_1 - 6TB
drwxrwxrwx 4 5001 users  4096 Apr 21 09:10 Films.2 - 6TB
drwxrwxrwx 5 5001 users  4096 Jul  7 10:57 Movies - 12TB

If I try to view the contents of the 12TB in file manager it reports "inode/x-corrupted type".
If i change to root user (sudo -i su) from the command line I can access all my files.
Is this some weird limit of a pi , I am running a pi 5 on the Pi OS full 64 bit.
All drives mount correctly on my linux laptop or on my samsung TV
It looks like some weird permission thing but I can't see how

Be sure you have a decent power supply - marginal power can lead to all manner of issues.

What filesystem format do your drives have? Use a native Linux one line ext4 or zfs; not NTFS or EXFAT.
